# Unsure how to find part of derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{5}{6x^5}+\tan(\frac{\pi}{9})$$

I'm reviewing questions and the derivative is supposed to be $$\frac{-25}{6}x^{-6}$$

But I can't remember how I got the $-\frac{25}{6}$. The rest I've got but not that.

Comment: Your answer is correct; I have shown a proof of it in my answer. You just need to use the sum rule and power rule of derivatives with a little algebra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with
$$\frac{5}{6x^5}+\tan(\pi/9)$$
Then we take derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg[\frac{5}{6x^5}+\tan(\pi/9)\bigg]$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{5}{6x^5}+\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\pi/9)$$
$$\frac{5}{6}\frac{d}{dx}x^{-5}$$
$$\frac{5}{6}(-5x^{-6})$$
$$\frac{-25}{6}x^{-6}$$

Answer (score 0):

For starters, $\tan(\frac{\pi}{9})$
is a constant, so won't show up in your final solution. (The derivative of a constant is $0$.).

That leaves you with 
$$\frac{5}{6x^5}$$

Rewrite it and use the power rule.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{5}{6}x^{-5}= -\frac{5\times 5}{6}x^{-6}=-\frac{25}{6x^6}$$